# What to use to build an enclosure for projector screen case?

Tags: wood, ceiling, finishing, custom-cabinetry

I need to create an enclosure for a projector screen case mounted on the ceiling. The size is 50 inches wide, 4 inches high, 4 inches deep.

Requirements:

- The enclosure is just for visuals, just to hide the plastic case of the projector screen, so it creates a more "built-in" looking.
- It will be finished just like the ceiling: white.
- Must be lightweight. I can't use thick wood (probably your first thought!). I was thinking about some kind of very thin wood (I remember seeing them before, they are a little flexible but stay straight if no force is applied). Remember the idea here is just to hide the projector screen case, nothing else. So less is better!
- It must be easily removable. It means this enclosure will not be attached to the ceiling, but will just use something to attach it to the projector screen case (that's why it needs to be lightweight). Don't worry about how to attach it, if it's lightweight even a velcro will make it. It is because the projector screen is battery powered so occasionally it is necessary to replace the battery.
- Ideas about how to finish (specially the sides) so it looks like something built to the ceiling.

The whole idea is just to hide the plastic casing.

I'm looking mainly for ideas about what materials to use to create the enclosure, what to use to connect the sides, what to use to finish it.

Thank you!

Comment: How will you attach it to the ceiling? What are the dimensions of the screen? What are the dimensions of the space in which the enclosure should live? It's always best to start with a drawing containing the initial measurements.

Comment: i would use foamcore and magnets or command strips. you might need to go to 1/4" drywall for the long run, as foam core usually maxes out at 48.

Comment: @DavidD Thanks, I'm more interested in knowing what materials to use to build the enclosure. My question is not about how to attach it. I provide the dimensions in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Think about running down to you hobby shop or home store and checking out their supply of balsa wood. That stuff is really light and easy to work with. It comes in many different sizes, sheets and square stock. It can be glued with regular wood glue or super glue and can be painted to match the ceiling.

Comment: Great! Was looking for recommendations like that! I'm not familiar with the names, so I don't even know how to search for them. If you have any other idea, please share! Thank you!

Comment: Yup, balsa wood sounds ideal for this situation. You can cut it with a sharp hobby knife or pocket knife, so it doesn't even require any special tools. You do want to be aware that it's somewhat brittle - a 50" long piece will want to go all wobbly on you and will likely snap if not handled gently. It may also be a bit pricey to get that much balsa, but it is an _excellent_ option.

Comment: @FreeMan I've seen them before, I remember exactly what you described. Managed properly, it is the best option I believe.

Comment: Would you use wood glue or maybe metal L bracket to secure the sides? Can I just paint them with white paint or need anything extra?

Comment: @igorjrr both of your questions are addressed in the answer above.

Comment: @igorjrr  Glue or Velcro...  or double sided tape. I doubt you'd need the metal l brackets.

Comment: @FreeMan and JACK the lumber I use does not carry balsa, but has Lauan wood 1/8 thick. Are you familiar with that, would it work for me? Thanks for helping!

Comment: @igorjrr  I'm unfamiliar with Lauan wood but I have to imagine it's heavier than balsa wood.  Try a few other locations, home stores, hobby, arts and crafts.

Comment: @igorjrr Highly unlikely you'd find balsa at the home improvement center. I would consider it somewhat unusual to find it at a lumber yard. It is, in the US at least, well within the realm of hobby/model making and or arts & crafts. Luan is usually the veneer used on interior doors, I wouldn't think it would have much structural strength and would probably be more floppy than balsa. With balsa, you could probably go 1/4" for strength and still be about as light as the Luan. Which you choose, though, is up to you

Answer (score 1):

1/8" (or 3mm) melamine faced "hardboard" (what Masonite® is but that's a brand name rather than the generic product.) Thin, fairly light, will need a saw to cut it, already white (on one face.)

Or skip the building supply store, head to the art supply store, and get some "foamcore" used for making 3-D architectural models (among many other uses) - cuts easily with a sharp knife, already white, very lightweight.

Comment: Thanks for the foamcore idea! I'll certainly check, seems to be a lightweight material that could work. Would you say it blends well with a white ceiling (that is, won't call too much attention)? If wood I know would look good, but I'm not familiar with the foamcore. Thank you!

Comment: Foamcore is another excellent suggestion!

Comment: if you go foamcore, you can easily build a box by gluing wood or styrofoam blocks in the inside corners. You can also make it look quite nice (hiding the layered edges) by gluing outside corner trim along the edges. A lot of my house is foamcore (eg wainscoting panels) and 3d-printed plastic, and I often joke: "Hey watch out! that's load-bearing foamcore!"...

Comment: @dandavis Thank you! Could you please clarify the "...by gluing outside corner trim". Sorry, I could not understand what outside corner trim refers to.

Comment: trim is long skinny pieces of wood/pvc used to decorate a house. Inside corner trim includes quarter-round and cove, which you could use to hold the box together. Outside corner molding looks kind of like two yardsticks glued together in an elbow. google "outside corner trim" for examples and shopping links.